# passing id in (click) to another component or route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-component-router

I need to pass an id along with a click event to another component

here is the component.ts

```
 editData(rcid){
      this.router.navigate(['/Editdata']);
  }
```

**rcid** is the id of the clicked item. And router"/editdata" is where the id is to be passed.

I had checked with session and local storage but it need to refresh the page when coming with another  id

please help me with this. I'm new to angular

Comment: why don't you pass it in route?using query or path param.

Comment: @AakashGarg I don't know  can you show an example

Comment: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-passing-parameters-to-route/

Comment: @AakashGarg the id is passed to component but I need it in service component. Is there a way?

Comment: it can be a component or a service, what is service component?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a second argument to `navigate` that implements `NavigationExtras` [interface](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras):

```
this.router.navigate(['/Editdata'], { state: { id: '123' } });
```

at your receiving component you can extract it:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.id = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.id;
}
```

Comment: it showed me this error `Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!`